# How to initialize a genetic algorithm (GA) with a specific population in Python

Tags: python, random, theano, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

The following equations show a randomly initial population for a genetic algorithm by Python.
`toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)`

`toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, 
    toolbox.attr_bool, 100)`

`toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)`

The question is how to initialize the population with a specific matrix? I am not interested in starting a GA with randomly initialization.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best answer found in "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/deap-users/B_KaNroEJjE". It is from Google group